# Detect contour into the method cv2.Circle

Tags: python, opencv

I am developing a project and would like a little help. I am using opencv + python for image processing, I use the Canny method to extract the edges of a can and I use findContour to draw the contours found by the Canny method ...

I draw the outline found in the image, then create a circle using the cv.Circle method as shown in the image:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45kfz.png)

The red circle is the circle created by the cv.Circle method.

The green circle is the outline found by the Canny method.

What I need now is to know if it is possible to identify whether any part of the green outline is into the red circle, is it possible to make this identification?

Script used:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor (image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.blur (gray, (3, 3))
edged = cv2.Canny (gray, canny1, canny1 * 3, kernel)
outline, hierarchy = cv2.findContours (edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
areas = [cv2.contourArea (contour) for contour in contour]
if areas:
    (contour, areas) = ​​zip (* sorted (zip (contour, areas), key = lambda a: a [1]))
    cnt = outline [-1]
    #print (areas)
    (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle (cnt)
    center = (int (x), int (y))
    radius = int (radius)
    circle = cv2.circle (image, center, radius - 10, (0,0,255), 2)
    circle = cv2.circle (image, center, radius + 10, (0,0,255), 2)
    cv2.drawContours (image, [outline [-1]], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow ('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged)
    cv2.imshow ('Contours', image)
```

Comment: Just for understanding: You get the green contour, and then do [`minEnclosingCircle`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8ce13c24081bbc7151e9326f412190f1) on that contour, but draw two different red circles (not reflected by your image!?), one with a slightly smaller and one with a slightly larger radius? (Why? Also: Code doesn't reproduce the image.) By definition, the whole green contour will be within the minEnclosingCircle, no checking needed. For the slightly smaller red circle, I'd stick to [fmw42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63983349/11089932).

Comment: @HansHirse, Thanks for the answer !
I will explain a little better, I drew two red circles to judge if a can is good for use.
if the green circle (Canny Method) is between the largest and smallest red circle (cv.Circle Method) the can is good!
follow the image.
Bad can: [link](https://imgur.com/qUPyHNB)
Good can: [link](https://imgur.com/xJkWNEx)

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**

According to [OpenCV Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours),

> contours – Detected contours. Each contour is stored as a vector of points.

You can manually calculate the points of the circle (or [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) in your case)

Now that you have both the points, you can perform an *intersection of both*

And then later plot the intersection

**Approach 2**

1. Generate 2 Different images of a fixed colour other than green and red
2. One with Circles and contours on them (your current image) (green and red)
3. Now remove all Red Color from Image and replace it with the background color
4. Generate an Image with the Contours (green)
5. Find the absolute difference between both the images
6. Et viola. What remains are indeed your points

Answer (score 0):

Test each (x,y) point on the contour relative to the center of the circle and its radius:

```
if (x-center_x)**2 + (y-center_y)**2 <= radius**2:
   # inside circle
```